# Image File Path get from shared folder Asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net, api, web

My ASp.net WebApi(2) project hosted in iiS, here employee image get  from another shared folder (its not under the IIS) 
(192.168.100.202/shared/photo/Shared/EmployeePhoto/32019/197416.Jpeg) ..
my client side is Angular 7 get image path in client side but not shoeing get an error "Not allowed to load local resource"

have any solution for showing the image and reference from api part

Answer (score 0):

You need to stream it from your server. Something like the below should work;

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetImage(int employeeId)
{
    // TODO: Adjust path by parameter employeeId...
    string picturePath = @"//192.168.100.202/shared/photo/Shared/EmployeePhoto/32019/197416.Jpeg";

    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(picturePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    HttpResponseMessage response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);

    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");

    return response;
}
```

(This is because the shared folder is not part of the web application and allowing access to external files would, among other problems, be a security risk.)

As you are using angular you can do something like this in you html (depending on what your bindings look like);

```
<img [src]="'api/MyController/GetImage?employeeId=' + employee.Id"
             onerror="this.onerror = null; this.src = 'content/images/StaticMissingPicture.png'; this.style = 'opacity: 0.5'; this.title = 'Could not get picture';"
             class="img-fluid rounded mx-auto d-block"
             alt="Employee picture" />
```